# how to implement a simple logo game like keyboard

Tags: java, android, button, layout, random

I am making a quiz game where the user has to enter the correct word via buttons which all have a letter on them. I want the buttons to display random letters although all of the letters required for the answer are there. Much like the text inputs for the logo quiz and 4 pics 1 word games. I have made an xml file which contains everything i need, i just need help to work out the java coding. To get the buttons with the correct answer letters mixed among other random letters is where i am having trouble. Would i somehow input the answer, then break it into indivudal letters, then asign each one to a button, then fill the remaining buttons with a random letter, and then randomise the layout?

I am fairly new to programing, although have not come arcoss anything that has stopped me like this. Thanks in advance for your resopnse

:D

Comment: a Simple Suggestion for this is go to play.google.com and search 4pic1word game and similar games downlaod any play and check thier concpet all you need is to show Buttons between 1-n and on click any button it`s text is displayed on the Field and also add a button of delete to delete text from field by single letter not a rocket science but your logic of implimentation and disable edit text field or text field from being clicked so that native keyboard may not pooed up

Answer (score 1):

If your answer is in your XML, you might read it from there and store it in a String.
As you probably know how many buttons you've got you could create an array with the size of the number of buttons in your game. Then you can input in the array all the char from your answer and complete the array with random letters.
After that you could randomly choose which button display which char.
That's just one suggestion